# Templates no cargan los archivos estáticos

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, template

Tengo un *template* que descargué de internet y estoy tratando de utilizarlo en mi proyecto Django pero no logro que carguen los archivos estáticos.

La carpeta del *template* tenia los *JS*, *CSS*, tipos de letra, entre otros, y las corté y pegué en una carpeta llamada "static" en la base del proyecto. Configuré el *settings.py* para mis archivos estáticos pero no se cargan los archivos.

No sé en que parte de esta configuración estoy fallando.

El directorio del proyecto es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**settings.py**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from my_apps.pacientes import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', include('my_apps.pacientes.urls',namespace="pacientes")), 
        ]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**urls.py de App**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from my_apps.pacientes.views import home #se importa el view home

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home), 
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import FormularioRegistro #importamos el formulario
# Create your views here.

def home(request): 

    f1 = FormularioRegistro()
    contexto = { 
    "formul" : f1,}

    return render(request,"base.html",contexto)
```

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>


    <title>Inicio</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'assets/icons/diente.ico' %}" />



    <script src="{% static 'js/sweet-alert.min.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/sweet-alert.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/normalize.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' %}"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/modernizr.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
</head>
.
.
.
```

No sé por qué no encuentra ni los estilos ni los demás archivos estáticos.

**Aqui una muestra de las rutas no encontradas por el servidor cuando se ejecuta `manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:81`**

```
Not Found: /home/static/js/sweet-alert.min.js
Not Found: /home/static/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css
Not Found: /home/static/css/sweet-alert.css
Not Found: /home/static/css/normalize.css
Not Found: /home/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
Not Found: /home/static/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:00] "GET /home/static/js/sweet-alert.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 228
4
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:00] "GET /home/static/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css
 HTTP/1.1" 404 2338
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:00] "GET /home/static/css/sweet-alert.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2278
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:00] "GET /home/static/css/normalize.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2272
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:00] "GET /home/static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 228
4
Not Found: /home/static/css/style.css
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:00] "GET /home/static/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css HTTP/1.
1" 404 2314
Not Found: /home/static/js/modernizr.js
Not Found: /home/static/js/bootstrap.min.js
Not Found: /home/static/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js
Not Found: /home/static/js/main.js
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:01] "GET /home/static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2260
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:01] "GET /home/static/js/modernizr.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2266
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:01] "GET /home/static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2278
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:01] "GET /home/static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2251
```

Comment: Hola, ¿te refieres a que no funcionan en tu ambiente de desarrollo?

Comment: Si @César, no funcionan en mi ambiente de desarrollo. Por los momentos estoy corriendo el proyecto en el servidor de Django

Answer (score 1):

**settings.py**
Prueba a quitar los slash en `STATICFILES_DIRS` y `STATIC_ROOT`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

Comment: realice los cambios que me sugeriste y no funciono, lo tengo de la siguiente manera 



STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = 'static' 

y aun así no funciona. Cualquier otra recomendación estaré al pendiente. Gracias!

Comment: Supongo que estas ejecutando en desarrollo, no? `./manage.py runserver`

Te muestra algún error o simplemente no cargan los static files?

Comment: Por cierto, los slashes también se han de quitar en `STATIC_URL`

Comment: Si @snicoper Estoy ejecutando en desarrollo. El servidor corre sin problemas con el `manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:81`,pero envia mensajes como estos `Not Found: /home/static/js/sweet-alert.min.js`
`Not Found: /home/static/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css`
`Not Found: /home/static/css/sweet-alert.css`
`Not Found: /home/static/css/normalize.css`
`Not Found: /home/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`
`Not Found: /home/static/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css`

El **html** carga sin problema pero los estaticos no. **Estoy corriendo con el puerto 81 porque por algun motivo el 80 no funciona**

Comment: Puedes poner la asignación de `BASE_DIR`? es que es raro que busque en `/home/static/*`

Comment: si, era raro que buscara en `/home/static` porque la manera correcta de colocar el `STATIC_URL` era asi `STATIC_URL='/static/'`

Comment: Toda la razón, va con slashes `STATIC_URL`

Answer (score 1):

Creo q este debe ser tu problema,
Estas usando en tu base.html la *templatetag* `{% load static %}` y esta carga los archivos estaticos q estan en **STATIC_ROOT**, deberias usar `{% load staticfiles %}` q busca los archivos estaticos dentro de las rutas correspondientes a tu configuracion de busqueda de ficheros estaticos o sea:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Espero q te resuelva.

Debes cambiar 
`STATIC_URL = 'static/'`

por

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

pues del modo q lo tienes puesto se pone como sufijo de la url actual, te puedes fijar aqui:

```
Not Found: /home/static/js/sweet-alert.min.js
[19/Dec/2017 19:21:00] "GET /home/static/js/sweet-alert.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 228
4
```

xq tu url inicial es /home

Saludos.

Comment: cambie el templatetag {% load static %} por {% load staticfiles %} y aun asi el problema persiste, los archivos estaticos no cargan. Editaré la pregunta con las respuestas sugueridas, pero el problema persiste. De igual modo si tienes alguna otra sugerencia te la agradezco. Saludos

Comment: Puedo ver el codigo en algun repositorio o lo puedes enviar por correo comprimdo para poderlo correr y ponerte la solucion aqui? Saludos

Comment: Creo q ya vi el error, fijate q tienes puesto STATIC_URL = 'static/' donde 'static/' debe ir asi '/static/' o sea STATIC_URL = '/static/', xq probe ahora y si pongo 'static/' sin el primer slash se pone como sufijo de la url actual en la q estes, y por lo tanto no encuentra los estilos. Saludos

Comment: perfecto, ya lo solucione! No me estaba dando cuenta del sufijo `home` como me lo mencionaste. Coloque la variable `STATIC_RUL=/static/` y funciono a la perfección. Tambien quité `STATIC_ROOT` de la configuracion porque me decia que `STATICFILES_DIRS` no podia contener la raiz estatica, asi que la quite y funciono! GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 0):

Si estás tratando de cargarlo en tu ambiente de desarrollo debes agregar la ruta en tus URLs como se muestra en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Otra razón por la que pienso que no podría funcionar es que estás utilizando mal las comillas en tu template. Por ejemplo:

```
<script src="{% static "js/sweet-alert.min.js" %}"></script>
```

Deberías hacerlo mezclando comillas dobles y simples:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/sweet-alert.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: ya habia agregado la ruta como lo muestra la documentacion, tal como lo mostre en la pregunta. Cambie las comillas en mi template realizando los cambios que me sugeriste y tampoco cargaron. No se que estará fallando. Si tienes alguna otra recomendación estaré al pendiente. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución era colocar `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` y no `STATIC_URL = 'static/'`.

También tenia que quitar `STATIC_ROOT = 'static'` ya que los `STATICFILES_DIRS` estaban buscando de manera errada, asi que lo quite y funcionó a la perfección